# How do I work with different graph databases using the Bolt neo4j python?

Tags: python, neo4j

My test using Python Neo4j Bolt was successful. During the test I had opened a graph database (lets call it "First.graphdb"). Then I opened another python file and wanted to call neo4j. This time I had another graph database opened (lets call it "Second.graphdb) and I couldnt get through. How do I know which graphdatabase I am using/updating?

Answer (score 0):

If you use two encrypted connections to the same host, you will get into trouble with the SSL certificate.

If you do the following, you will get a `ProtocolError` stating that the server certificate for the second connection does not match the known certificate for the first:

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth

g1 = GraphDatabase.driver('bolt://localhost:7687')

with g1.session() as s:
    s.run('MATCH (a) RETURN a')

g2 = GraphDatabase.driver('bolt://localhost:7787')

with g2.session() as s:
    s.run('MATCH (a) RETURN a')
```

The error message is:

```
ProtocolError: Server certificate does not match known certificate for 'localhost';
check details in file '/Users/someuser/.neo4j/known_hosts'
```

If you use unencrypted connections (by adding `encrypted=False` to the `driver()`) it works.

The simple solution is to delete the `known_hosts` file after using the first database. However, if you use both in parallel this will cause a lot of overhead. If both databases run on different hosts you should also be fine. Apart from that I don't really know much about dealing with certificates etc. Maybe there is a way to tell the driver which database on which port belongs to which certificate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very useful. 
Please let me know what are the recommended steps (for dummies) to open and begin a new work in the most simplest way to avoid adjustments (provided that I already have the pip flowing). 
For example:
1. Open Neo4J
2. Open Python IDE
3. import GraphDatabase module
4. etc
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use only one DB per host. You have to figure out yourself how to open an IDE, that's not really the point of Stack Overflow...